# Two overlapping panels with visible components

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have two transparent overlapping `JPanel` both inside of a container panel, using `CardLayout`.
I have components inside both panels, but even if they are both transparent, it is showing only the components inside the panel added for first inside the container:

```
panel1.setOpaque(false);
panel2.setOpaque(false);
container.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
container.add(panel1); //only components inside panel1 are shown
container.add(panel2); //if I change order, only components in panel2 are shown
```

Since I have buttons in `panel1` and labels in `panel2` (I need them to be like this), I would like to make both panels' components visible.

Comment: You're looking for a JLayeredPane I think, not a CardLayout.

Comment: did you use .pack() so that your components can allocate their needed space?

Comment: No I don't because I don't think that I need it, since components are on different panels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OverlayLayout`.

This layout is designed to display two components on top on one another.

The Swing tutorial doesn't have an example of this layout so you can check out: [Java Layout with Component always in Top Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703262/java-layout-with-component-always-in-top-right/38703764#38703764) for an example to help demonstrate how the layout works.