# Positioning of JButtons in a JPanel with BoxLayout over JLabel in JPanel with Overlaylayout

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a menu for my game. I want the background to be animated. Therefore I use a JLabel with a gif. On top of this I want my buttons. But, I want some air between the buttons and the left side of the window. That gives me trouble.

This is my result. It's pretty good! But I can't get the gray bar to disappear! Also, it looks like my background JLabel is being pushed a tad to the right.

[image: My result]

I have three classes:

1 The launcher that  creates the JFrame

```
public class Launcher extends JFrame{

    public int speed = 0;

    int c = 0;
    public final static int WIDTH = 1200;
    public final static int HEIGHT = 800;
    Game game;
    JFrame frame;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        new Launcher();


    }

    public Launcher() throws IOException{

        game = new Game();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PingPong!");
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT) );
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



    }




}
```

2 The Game that creates a JPanel with OverlayLayout

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    public State menuState;


    public Game() throws IOException{
        this.removeAll();
        this.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));

        menuState = new MenuState(this, handler);
    }
}
```

3 And finally my MenuState that creates a JPanel with BoxoLayout where I add the elements

```
public class MenuState extends State{

    JPanel menuPanel;

    JLabel background;

    private Icon backgroundIcon;

    private Icon newgameIcon;
    private Icon loadgameIcon;

    private JButton newGame;
    private JButton loadGame;

    Border border;

    public MenuState(Game game, Handler handler) {
        super(game, handler);       

        init();


    }       

    public void init(){

        menuPanel = new JPanel();
        menuPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        menuPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(100));
        menuPanel.setVisible(true);
        menuPanel.setOpaque(false);



        Box left = Box.createVerticalBox();

        backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon("res/images/menu/back.gif");
        background = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);

        newGame = new JButton("New Game");  
        loadGame = new JButton("Load Game");

        game.add(menuPanel);

        menuPanel.add(newGame);


        left.add(newGame);
        left.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 40)));
        left.add(loadGame);
        left.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 300)));
        left.setOpaque(false);


        menuPanel.add(left);

        background.setSize(1200, 800);
        game.add(background);   


    }


}
```

I have tried different order of adding the components. I have tried Opacity true and false.

I wish I could just set `newGame.setLocation(100, 500)` and the box would be placed where I wanted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, I want some air between the buttons and the left side of the window.

1. Add your buttons to a JPanel and make the JPanel non-opaque.
2. Then you can add an `EmptyBorder` to the panel to give the buttons spacing within the panel.
3. Then you add the panel to the overlay layout using the appropriate alignmentx/y values.

You can play with the alignment values using the demo code found here: [Java Layout with Component always in Top Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703262/java-layout-with-component-always-in-top-right/38703764#38703764)

If I understand your requirement you should be using setAlignmentX(0.0) and setAlignmentY(0.5);

So to simply your code it should be something like:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(...);
background.setAlignmentX(0.0f);
background.setAlignmentY(0.5f);

JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel( set your layout );
buttonsPanel.setOpaque( false );
buttonsPanel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(...) );
buttonsPanel.setAlignmentX(0.0f);
buttonsPanel.setAlignmentY(0.5f);

JPanel overlayPanel = new JPanel( new OverLayLayout(...) );
overlayPanel.add(background);
overlayPanel.add(buttonsPanel);
```

Comment: Hey, that worked perfectly! I sat the alignment to each of the panels, that didn't do much. I added the emptyborder, and that did it! I think I need to read up on what setAlignment does.

Thank you so very much! :D