# Creating a GUI using setBounds()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, setbounds

I read that it is bad to use the `setBounds()` command for creating GUIs.

I know how to use Layout Managers and I have to say that they also have their disadvantages.

I'm programming a Game at the Moment and sometimes I need to stack Components above each other. I found no way to do this using Layout Managers, but `setBounds()` works perfectly.

Could you explain how I can stack Components using Layout Managers and also tell me why it is bad to use the `setBounds()` method for this purpose?
Or is it fine, in conjunction with game GUIs coded in Java?

Comment: Show the code you have tried.  To stack components with a layout manager, use `Box.createVerticalBox()`.

Comment: I wouldn't use Swing nowadays to code any Java GUI, especially not one for a game. Have you had a look at JavaFX? It comes from an animation background, so it should be much better suited for your purposes.

Comment: Absolute positioning is probably fine for a game (depending on the game style, that is). If you want to stack things with layout managers, you may have a look at layered panes : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Comment: It's not about the code but a general question. And I don't want to put them underneath each other, but _on top_ of each other. So a part of the rear component is covered by the upper one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LayoutManagers take a lot of weight off your shoulders when it comes to stuff like calculating the correct size of a control, position everything in the right place when the GUI is resized etc.

Basically you just tell the layout manager "I want this control over there in the corner" and the layout manager is responsible for keeping it there, whatever happens to the window, whether the user resizes it, moves it around,...

A game interface is probably much more dynamically with elements constantly moving around. Layout managers usually are not particularly good at that stuff, they usually are designed for static user interfaces. Most desktop software (citation needed? ;) ) utilizes such static interfaces and layout managers are there to help the programmers of such interfaces so that they don't have to bother with all those details stated above.

As a game interface is a use case thats not ideal for a layout manager, it is absolutely justifiable to not use it for everything. Still you probably could use a combination of both techniques - use a layout manager to position your static interface elements (you ought to have a menu button somewhere or something similar?) but use absolute positioning for all your dynamic elements that are moving around.

Still, I'd recommend you looking into JavaFX, as stated in my comment above. It is much more better suited to draw animated, moving components and should save you a lot of work.

Of course there are always exceptions - for example a Sudoku interface is something that you can do very well with layout managers, although it definitely is a game.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you explain how I can stack Components using Layout Managers and also tell me why it is bad to use the setBounds() method for this purpose? Or is it fine, in conjunction with game GUIs coded in Java?

Define stack?

Swing comes with a layout manager for stacking components. Check out the `OverlayLayout`. It is not the most flexible but you can experiment with the code in: [Java Layout with Component always in Top Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703262/java-layout-with-component-always-in-top-right/38703764#38703764) to if it does what you want.

Or, you can check out the [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) which is a little more flexible with its layout properties.

Finally you can also add a JLabel to a JLabel. Use one label as a background. Then you can set the layout manager of that label and then add another Swing component.